# Building emacs for Alpine Linux info/dir target failure

Tags: linux, build

I am trying to build emacs for Alpine Linux by following the instructions.
After installing the relevant packages I run

`configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid --with-mailutils --enable-gcc-warnings --with-modules --enable-link-time-optimization`

Then I run make and I run into the following problem

`make info/dir`

throws

`awk: bad regex '@value{emacsname}': Invalid contents of {}`

The problematic line is in `make-info-dir:L41`

`gsub(/@value{emacsname}/, "Emacs")`

Any guess as to why that happens?
If I delete the line it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, for some reason emacs is not happy with the busybox awk.
Installing gawk seems to resolve the problem.